# Example of a bijection on $\{0,1\}^n$ which is not a linear transformation

Tags: combinatorics

> I am trying to find an example of a bijection on $\{0,1\}^n$ which is not a linear transformation.

I am looking for a bijection $f$ that has a closed form expression i.e. can be expressed by a succinct formula. Clearly, $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ can be arranged in some fixed order (like lexicographic, etc) and a bijection can be defined that cycles through this ordering in some way. But this bijection may not have an explicit closed form expression. So I was wondering if there is one? Thanks.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "not a linear transformation"? Do you mean "not 'flip particular entries'"?

Comment: Indeed, I have the same question as Arthur: I am puzzled by the term "non linear", if you consider it as equivalent "which does not come from the application of a $n \times n$ permutation matrix" you will find no other transformation...

Comment: @Arthur By this I mean, the bjiection $f$ cannot be represented by a matrix $A$.

Comment: @JeanMarie If $f$ can be represented by a matrix $A$, then any such $A$ fixes the all zero vector i.e. $A\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}$. But there clearly would be bijections $f$ on $\{0,1\}^n$ s.t. $f(\textbf{0})\neq \textbf{0}$.

Comment: Good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1 to each component (operation made mod 2) which is equivalent to take the "xor" (eXclusive OR) operation componentwise with the "all-ones vector" $U$. In this way the image of the null vector is $U$ which prevents the operation to be linear...

The bijectivity of this transformation results from the bijectivity of the "xor" operation on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Sorry, aren't there $(2^n)!$ bijections on $\{0,1\}^n$? So as I understand, the $n!$ permutation matrices do not fill all the possibilities of bijections on $\{0,1\}^n$? I must be missing something.

Comment: You are right. Here is a completely changed answer.

Comment: If you want to write this in a way that's not dependent on mod 2, you can say $x\mapsto (1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1) - x$.

Comment: @Arthur Nice observation. Thanks.